# Can I use PHP define() function to change multiple die(mysql_error()) outputs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application I wrote in PHP. I use a single Class to handle almost everything this app does. I predefine a few things before the class such as database name. What I was hoping for is that I could set a define for mysql_error().

So when I run a SQL query and add die() of error, I want it to ouput "An Error Has Occurred!" if the app is running in a production environment, but then I can change the 1 define from define("DIEOUTPUT", "An Error Has Occurred!") to define("DIEOUTPUT", mysql_error());

My die() function looks like: die(DIEOUTPUT);

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'd encourage you to take advantage of a logger library or create a custom `Logger` object instead of littering the code with `die()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

Instead, you could create your own version of `die()`:

```
function my_die(){
    if($is_production_environement) {
        die("An error has occured");
    }
    else{
        var_dump(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**Note**:

- You should consider moving away from `mysql_*` functions to PDO or mysqli.
- Using `die()` (or `my_die()` for that matter) on a real webpage is not too userfriendly, consider alternatives

Comment: $is_production_environement should be a global variable, or i prefer using a constant instead.

Comment: @RezaSh It's only symbolic for whatever goes best with your codebase. It may be a function to check, it may be a global constant... You can use whatever you like ;)

Comment: you are true,but you have already done everything , your code is more realastic thant a symbolic version ;) :d

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- You should not use mysql_ function, prefer mysqli_ functions, they are more secured, efficient and has access to new features
- a constant in php has to be statically defined. You can't use define with a function call.

Your code, with mysqli, should look like :

```
mysqli_query('your query') or exit($isProduction?"An error occured":mysqli_error());
```

According to your desire of using a constant, you can use

```
define(PRODUCTION,true);//false if dev
mysqli_query('your query') or exit(PRODUCTION?"An error occured":mysqli_error());
```